# HTML special characters does not replaced by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to decode some specail characters in my string, before input it in HTML. But, for some reason, it didn't work.
For ex:

My input string is "ampere 13th\'."

In JS I'm replacing every special character with this function:

```
htmlEntities: function(str) {
    return str.replace(/\\/g, "&#92;").replace("'", "&#39;").replace(".", "&#46;").replace("%", "&#37;").replace("\"","&#34;");
},
```

But, when put it to HTML, it still looks like :
"ampere 13th\'."

I want to show my data with replaced special characters.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: It depends on how you put it into your HTML. `&#39;` is the HTML entity for `'`, so placing `&#39;` into HTML will render... guess what... `'`.

Comment: @deceze So, is it any way of put in html special sybmols lile I want to do it? Or it will alwayls be transformed?

Comment: Again, it depends on how you insert the text. If you're using `innerHTML`, use `innerText` instead! Otherwise, escape the escape sequence to `&amp;#39;`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single backslash in your string which is not being recognized as '\' but instead its an escape sequence. Other characters are being replace perfectly. I have written the following function which alerts the output string accordingly.

```
 function test() {
        var str = "ampere 13th\'.";
        alert(str.replace(/\\/g, "&#92").replace("'", "&#39;").replace(".", "&#46;").replace("%", "&#37;").replace("\"", "&#34;"));
    }
```

And it alerts me

```
ampere 13th&#39;&#46;
```

which is correct except replacing the '\' character. if you want to replace the '\' you can further search on how to replace a backslash character in java script.

if I have my input string like this

```
var str = "ampere 13th\\'.";
```

with two backslashes then the replacement occurs perfectly and my function alerts me

```
ampere 13th&#92&#39;&#46;
```